# Asp.net MVC post json KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a model in c# which is

```
public class MyModelRequest { 
    public Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<int, int>> Data {get;set;}
}
```

I want to post to an action of a controller and bind to this model.

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyAction([FromBody] MyModelRequest model) {}
```

I thought it was something like that I need to post :

```
{data: {
aname: {0, 10},
asecondname: {10, 5}
}}
```

But it's not working. KeyValuePair contain 0, 0 instead of correct value. Any idea how to post that ?

Comment: Is that a model or a property which is part of a model ? How are you posting ? to where ?

Comment: Include the code base on how are you constructing the JSON before posting.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with information given???  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: nested dictionaries does not play well with model binding. Use a POCO for your structure.

Comment: @Eric I think I now how to ask a question but it’s more you who need to check about politeness. Thanks.

Comment: @Shyju ok maybe it’s the solution. I will try it. Thanks. I wanted to achieve it with simple keyvaluepair but I’m not able to do it.

Comment: @Shyju I finally ended with what you said. I think your comment should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct structure should look like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "aname": {
      "key": 0,
      "value": 10
    },
    "asecondname": {
      "key": 10,
      "value": 5
    }
  }
}

public class MyModelRequest
{
    public Dictionary<string, MyKeyValuePair> Data { get; set; }
}
public class MyKeyValuePair
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Using the custom MyKeyValuePair class allows the binding to work with the JSON provided. Not ideal since you were looking for a native solution with KeyValuePair, but it may give you a path that will work for you without a custom model binder.

Comment: No sorry. Key Value specify was my first attempt but it not the good when to send data to asp.net mvc. Same for a dictionary. It’s not an array ok key/value object but a single object.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try writing a custom model binder and covert your Json to the format you want. 
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1368/aspnet-core-mvc-custom-model-binding. You can see this link to know how to write custom binders

Comment: Yes it can be a solution but to much for such a small thing. Moreover I’m pretty sure we can bind to a keyvaluepair natively

Answer (score -1):

It looks more like you need this model:

```
[
{aname,{0, 10}},
{asecondname, {10, 5}}
]
```

Comment: No sorry, this doesn’t work. A dictionary is not an array but un object and keys are the properties of that object. It’s how it works. It’s not the dictionary which is not bonded but it’s value which is KeyValuePay<int, int>

Comment: Ok, I got what you say. I guess you can try to use Newtonsoft to serialize you Dictionary, inspect what you get, and use the resulting structure in the call you are trying to make